# For loop Shell script program to find the latest file in a particular pattern

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, scripting

I am pretty new to shell scripting and I have a scenario where I have a text file which has a list of versions like

```
1.0.3
1.0.4
1.0.4_a12
1.0.4_b12
```

and I want to extract the latest version value without `_` in it. I want the output of the file to be `1.0.4`. Could anyone kindly provide some help such that I can write the script? Appreciate it.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Are there other files in the directory where you try to find the most recent version?

Comment: Take a look at regular expressions, you could filter them out that way, then you can do a simple file name comparison to get the one with the highest number.

Comment: A `for` loop is not necessary. I suggest you to remove that element from the question, but feel free to show what you have tried, even if it is with a `for` loop.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Yes please it can be done without for loop. I have removed that from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ls * | grep -v '_' | sort -V -r | head -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed 's/_.*$//g' < input file | sort -n |  head -1
```

Comment: I was trying something similar but head needs to be replaced with tail

Comment: This is not the way to sort according to version numbers. Instead of `sort -n`, you have to use `sort -V`. In this particular case, it worked, but it will not work in other cases.